# NGgrid not refreshing after update in modal window

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, ng-grid

User can update value for multiple rows in an nggrid using a modal window. After user confirms update and closes modal window, grid does not refresh. Navigating away from page and coming back indicates that the update took effect, but I want this to take effect right away, without having to use location.reload(). Any ideas?

Comment: Its good story, but can you post the relevant code? or better - reproduce it in fiddle/plunker

Answer (score 0):

If your modal is a directive I'm guessing (without having seen the code) that you need a $scope.$apply in the directive...